# Can anyone recommend a forex trading API?

Tags: trading

I'm interested in experimenting a bit with foreign exchange trading using PHP, JavaScript and the new HTML 5 canvas object. I've looked around a bit, but was wondering of a JavaScript API I can use for foreign exchange trading.

Can anyone recommend anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.forex.com/uk/forex-api.html

Comment: Link no longer Available, use this one: https://www.forex.com/en-uk/trading-platforms/more-services/api-trading  -  for US residents use https://www.forex.com/en-us/trading-platforms/more-services/api-trading

Answer (score 1):

there is a JSON API with all major forex currencies provided by [apirates.com](http://apirates.com/)